# Get all childs of a tree recursively

Tags: php, algorithm

My problem is the following:
I want to get all the sub-zones of a zone.
Each zone has a code that defines that zone, and a parent zone that points to its parent.

So example:

I have zone X with code = 2058. I want all the sub-zones of that zone
I get Y with code = 123, parent = 2058, and Z with code = 500, parent = 2058
Now I want all sub-zones of Y and Z. I will use the codes [123,500] and repeat the process until a zone doesnt have any childs.

This is the code I have done, but I get some error.
By the way im using a PHP framework but I hope you understand the code.

```
public function findChild($code)
{
    $result = array();
    $result = $this->db->get_where('zones', array('parent' => $code))->result();
    if(empty($result)) {
        return array();
    } else {
        foreach($result as $zone) {
            $temp = $this->findChild($zone['code']);
            $rr = array_merge($result, $temp);
        }
    }
    return $rr;
}
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to tackle this problem?

The result I get is only the childs with depth = 1.
So if code = 2058, I am only getting the childs that have parent = 2058.

Comment: `but I get some error`. What is the error?

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: Post edited with the result (error) I get.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was just a variable misplaced.
Anyways if anyone has a problem similar to this, the solution will be very similar to my approach.

```
public function findChild($code)
{
    $result = $this->db->get_where('zones', array('parent' => $code))->result();
    if(empty($result)) {
        return array();
    } else {
        foreach($result as $zone) {
            $temp = $this->findChild($zone->code);
            $result = array_merge($result, $temp);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I was using `$rr` as the result of the array merge, which is not actually correct. I should merge the original array. So with my previous code I was merging the same thing all the time.

Comment: Thanks, but you also changed `$zone['code']` to `$zone->code`. That was not part of the problem?

Comment: No that part was not.

Comment: I am sure this code would not scale since you are querying on each recursive call.